# Is it a good practice to serialize Parcelable objects for persistent storage?

Tags: android, arraylist, parcelable, serializable

I have two objects that implement the interface `Item`:

```
public interface Item extends Parcelable{//unneeded stuff}
```

I want to store an `ArrayList<Item>` persistently. Is making the `Items` Serializable a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

Neither Parcelable nor Serializable are a good idea for persisting data. Store persistent data in SharedPreferences if possible, or wind it out to a file.

Serializable could hit you if you decide to change the structure of the object. Parcelable is not guaranteed to remain constant across versions; it's designed to pass data between processes, not store data.

If you want to store data long-term, you should write it to a file. Depending on how you want to access it, you may want to store it in a database or a content provider.

Comment: The application I am developing is a shopping list, so I want data to be stored long term. How do you recommend I write the data to a file? I mean, in what format? Maybe using Gson?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you make an object parcelable/serializable depending on your need. If you need that data to recreate your UI, pass into the bundle etc. then you would make it serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Making object `Serializable` doesn't force you to use any particular serialization method. Generic Java serialization is quite inefficient, but nothing prevents you from making `Serializable` use Android parcelization (just marshal `Parcel` to the stream in `writeObject`)

But I doubt you really need serialization for data persistence. Shared preferences or database work better in most cases.